# ResourceNotFoundException but resource exists

Tags: google-drive-api

Randomly getting a ResourceNotFoundException on Google drive files when using the api.
They work for days and after a while simply refuse to get downloaded via API.
I can still access them from the UI and all permission settings are OK, but API access is broken.
Any ideas?

```
com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: OK
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" ><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/documents/images/kix-favicon5.ico"><title>Google Docs -- Page Not Found</title><link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><style>/* Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */
.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{color:#91959c;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;font-size:27px;font-weight:300;position:absolute;text-shadow:0 1px 1px white;white-space:nowrap}#drive-logo img{padding:0 0.4em 0 0;position:relative;top:2px;vertical-align:middle}#drive-logo a{color:#91959c;text-decoration:none}#drive-logo span.goog-inline-block{margin-top:3px;vertical-align:top}</style><style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a: link, a: visited {color: #112ABB;}</style><style type="text/css">.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}</style></head><body><div style="margin: auto; max-width: 750px;"><div style="margin: 80px 40px 20px 40px; position:relative; "><div style="position: absolute; top: -80px;"><h1 id="drive-logo"><a href="/"><img src="//www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" width="116" height="41" alt="Google logo" ><span class="goog-inline-block">Drive</span></a></h1></div><div align="center"><p class="errorMessage" style="padding-top: 50px">Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested does not exist.</p><p>Make sure that you have the correct URL and that the owner of the document hasn&#39;t deleted it.</p><div style="background: #F0F6FF; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 35px; padding: 10px 125px; width: 300px;"><p><strong>Want to create your own online docs?</strong></p><p>Google Docs makes it easy to create, store and share online documents, spreadsheets and presentations.</p><p>Learn more at <a href="https://docs.google.com">docs.google.com</a>.</p></div></div></div></div></body></html>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:599)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource(MediaService.java:234)
    at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:286)
    at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:302)
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solutions are the root cause of this problem ? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the older Gdata library instead of the new Drive SDK. That's not to say it shouldn't work, just that it's no longer the preferred API. The Drive SDK is much better supported by documentation and tooling.

It's a bit odd that you're getting back an HTML page instead of a simple API response. What URL are you using?